# Islam itself allows for contemplation of other religions as paths toward God?

Tags: practical-islam, islamic-philosophy

I stumbled upon this statement in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Islam_and_Sikhism&oldid=682808986#Social_beliefs) :

> *Islam itself allows for contemplation of other religions as paths toward God as long as those paths do not ascribe partners to Allah* (please find it using <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>)

How can other religions be used as a path to God, when Islam is the only religion in the eye of Allah? ([Quran 3:85](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.hilali/3:85))

Would anyone please explain what is meant by this statement and how is this *allowance* used in practice ?

Comment: This statement is false, consider that anyone can edit wikipedia stuff, so don't grant everything to be true on wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a scholar, but what could probably be the meaning is that one could in the search of truth learn different faiths.
This is applicable for people who are not Muslims.

For Muslims since they know that Islam is the truth they can still learn about the other faiths and appreciate the correctness and accuracy and wisdom of Quran, the only unchanged book on earth. People when reading the original text (unedited version) of other Abrahamic faiths definitely appreciate the word of god and the lessons contained within.

I know a lot of people who in pursuit of learning religions read each religious book and eventually stumbled upon Quran and became a Muslim. I study the bible myself and would definitely want to study the Torah some day. I understand this is an edited version but Islam commands you to be good to your neighbor and I wish to understand the person and their faith.

Hope this helps and Allah knows best.

Comment: If Islam commands you to be good to your neighbor, what is 9:5 all about?

Comment: It is all about war and when a war breaks out. It is the enemy its referring to and not the neighbor be it whoever unless the neighbor is standing with the enemy to fight you.

Comment: I think 9:1 states clearly, that it applies to disbelievers with whom we made a non-aggression pact.

Comment: Then you also must have read 9:4. It clearly supports my comment above.
Also I am not here to debate with anyone. We as people should strive to serve humanity and not pin point our findings to whomever we find. If there's a mosque near you, you're more than welcome to reach out to a scholar there and they can answer your questions in greater detail.